# Failure connecting JLink with Android Studio -Java application

Tags: java, application

I want to connect an android application with Mathematica, in order to make some computations and then return the results to the user. I have downloaded Mathmatika and run the Examples from JLink library in commandline. Everything works fine. The problem is when I enter the code in Android Studio.

The code I am using is this:

```
import com.wolfram.jlink.*;
public class vathmou extends ActionBarActivity {

Button lbtn;
Button clear_btn;

EditText a1;
EditText b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    KernelLink ml = null;
    String argv ="-linkmode launch -linkname \"C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/10.4/MathKernel.exe\"";
    System.out.println("OK1 ");

    try {
        ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink(argv);
        System.out.println("OK ");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (MathLinkException  e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fatal error opening link: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        System.out.println("Fatal error opening link: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Get rid of the initial InputNamePacket the kernel will send
        // when it is launched.
        ml.discardAnswer();

        ml.evaluate("<<MyPackage.m");
        ml.discardAnswer();

        ml.evaluate("2+2");
        ml.waitForAnswer();

        int result = ml.getInteger();
        System.out.println("2 + 2 = " + result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2+2 " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Here's how to send the same input, but not as a string:
        ml.putFunction("EvaluatePacket", 1);
        ml.putFunction("Plus", 2);
        ml.put(3);
        ml.put(3);
        ml.endPacket();
        ml.waitForAnswer();
        result = ml.getInteger();
        System.out.println("3 + 3 = " + result);


        String strResult = ml.evaluateToOutputForm("4+4", 0);
        System.out.println("4 + 4 = " + strResult);

    } catch (MathLinkException e) {
        System.out.println("MathLinkException occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        ml.close();
    }
    }
    }
```

The error I get is the one below:

> Could not find class 'java.awt.Window', referenced from method com.wolfram.jlink.KernelLinkImpl.addTitleChangeListener
>       Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/wolfram/jlink/MathJFrame; (2233)
>       Link of class 'Lcom/wolfram/jlink/MathJFrame;' failed
>       Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/wolfram/jlink/ui/ConsoleWindow; (1894)
>       Link of class 'Lcom/wolfram/jlink/ui/ConsoleWindow;' failed
>       Could not find method com.wolfram.jlink.ui.ConsoleWindow.getInstance, referenced from method com.wolfram.jlink.KernelLinkImpl.getConsole

Have I done something wrong? Could anyone please help me, please?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I'm trying to understand the goal you have in mind. Android Studio is used to make apps for the Android platform. As far as I know Mathematica is not (yet) available for that platform, but I may have missed the announcement.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I want to use a theorem that is only available on Mathematica (VAS theorem for root isolation) and I am trying to combine these two tools in order to get a result. Have you heard about any other tool-program that could help me?

Comment: Sorry, no. The point I was trying to make is that I don't understand how your idea was ever going to work. I assume that Studio is simulating an Android environment for which a Wolfram Engine  is not yet available. So I don't see how you could link to it.